# Прослушивание музыки на сайте и серфинг по сайту (образец : vk.com)

Tags: php, html, javascript

"В какую сторону смотреть", чтобы можно было слушать музыку на сайте, переходить по страницам, но музыка все равно играет )) 
Варианты с новым окном не интересны

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/16774

Answer (score 2):

Ключевые запросы: **replaceState**, **pushState**

JS плагины:

- [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) ([форк](https://github.com/ckald/jquery-pjax) с поддержкой якорей для старых браузеров)
- [address](https://github.com/asual/jquery-address) (поддерживает якоря)
- [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) (поддерживает якоря)

Неплохая подборка плагинов для HTML5-фитч от разработчиков Modernizr: [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) (думаю, пригодиться).

Собственно, контент подгружается ajax-ом.

Comment: А для старых браузеров шо делать? Ничаво? пусть обновляются?)

Comment: @vinnie Все плагины, кроме pjax, поддерживают старые браузеры, только вместо очевидной смены url-а, вставляют хэш-якорь **#** (http://yoursite.com/#!/news/) - иначе никак.